# Keep shown div open on hover

Tags: jquery

I have a link that when hovered it shows another div outside of the link, when I move the mouse into the newly shown div I need it to stay. At the moment as soon as the focus is off the link by moving over the shown div of course it disappears.

Got to be really simple surely, here is what I have at the mo:

```
$('a.tel').hover(function() {
    $('.phonePanel').fadeToggle().addClass('show');
});
```

Comment: A fiddle would be really nice. How about you remove the .fadeToggle()

Comment: You could replace hover with 'mouseenter' as this is only called when entering the element and not when exiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this should help.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3y6yjk3y/

```
var hoverTimeout, keepOpen = false, stayOpen = $('.stay-open'); 
$(document).on('mouseenter','.trigger',function(){
    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
    stayOpen.addClass('show');
}).on('mouseleave','.trigger',function(){
    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        if(!keepOpen){
            stayOpen.removeClass('show');   
        }
    },1000);
});

$(document).on('mouseenter','.stay-open',function(){
    keepOpen = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
        keepOpen = false;
    },1500);
}).on('mouseleave','.stay-open',function(){
    keepOpen = false;
    stayOpen.removeClass('show');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure what you are looking for but here is some quick code that shows a div and stays visible until you hover over that div and then exit. Wasn't sure what you were doing with that show class so I added it in example but it doesn't actually do anything in my example.

I believe your issue is that you passed a single handler and according to jQuery docs when you pass a single handler to `hover` it is run on hover in and hover out.

https://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover-handlerInOut

From docs:

> The .hover() method, when passed a single function, will execute that
>   handler for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. This allows the
>   user to use jQuery's various toggle methods within the handler or to
>   respond differently within the handler depending on the event.type.

In my example below you can see an example of giving a single handler or two.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x4fo4zkk/

HTML:

```
<a id="show">show more</a>
<div id="more">here is more</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#show').hover(
    function () {
        $('#more').fadeIn();
    }
);

$('#more').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass('show');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('show').fadeOut();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done purely with CSS if you can include a wrapper around both elements. Or if it has to be jQuery, the wrapper would help anyway.

HTML

```
<div class="phoneWrapper">
    <a class="tel">show more</a>
    <div class="phonePanel">here is more</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.phonePanel { display:none; }
.phoneWrapper:hover .phonePanel { display:block }
```

jQuery Alternative:

```
$('.phoneWrapper').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).children('.phonePanel').addClass('show');
});

$('.phoneWrapper').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).children('.phonePanel').removeClass('show');
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/v3txspx9/